# Retaining rows that have percent overlapping ranges in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, recursion, overlap

I have a dataframe with the columns:

```
[id, range_start, range_stop, score]
```

If two rows have a range overlap by `x` percentage I retain the row with the higher score. However, I am confused how to pull out rows with no overlap to other ranges. I am using a nested loop and recursion to condense overlapping ranges into a new dataframe. However, this structure causes all rows to be retained when I am looking for the non overlapping rows.

```
## This is my function to recursively select the highest scoring overlapping regions

def overlap_retention(df_overlap, threshold, df_nonoverlap=None):
     if df_nonoverlap != None:
          df_nonoverlap = pd.DataFrame()
     
     df_overlap = pd.DataFrame() 
    
     for index, row in x.iterrows():
          rs = row['range_start']
          re = row['range_end']

          ## Silly nested loop to compare ranges between all rows 
          for index2, row2 in x.drop(index).iterrows():   
               rs2 = row2['range_start']
               re2 = row2['range_end']
               readRegion=[*range(rs,re,1)]
               refRegion=[*range(rs2,re2,1)]
               regionUnion = set(readRegion).intersection(set(refRegion))
               overlap_length = len(regionUnion)
            
               overlap_min = min(rs, rs2)
               overlap_max = max(re, re2)
               overlap_full_range = overlap_max-overlap_min

               overlap_percentage = (overlap_length/overlap_full_range)*100

               ## Check if they overlap by x_percentage and retain the higher score
               if overlap_percentage>x_percentage:
                    evalue = row['score']
                    evalue_2 = row2['score']
            
                    if evalue_2 > evalue:
                          df_overlap = df_overlap.append(row2)
                    else:
                         df_overlap = df_overlap.append(row)
#----------------------------------------------------------
                ## How to find non-overlapping rows without pulling everything?
               else:
                    df_nonoverlap = df_nonoverlap.append(row)
# ---------------------------------------------

          ### Recursion here to condense overlapped list further
          if len(df_overlap)>1:
              overlap_retention(df_overlap, threshold, df_nonoverlap)
          else:
              return(df_nonoverlap)
```

An example input is below:

```
data = {'id':['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4', 'id5', 'id6'],
       'range_start':[1,12,11,1,20, 10],
       'range_end':[4,15,15,6,23,16],
       'score':[3,1,8,2,5,1]}
input = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'range_start', 'range_end', 'score'])
```

The desired output can change based on the overlap threshold. In the example above `id1` and `id4` may both be retained or simply `id1` depending on the overlap threshold:

```
data = {'id':['id1', 'id3', 'id5'],
       'range_start':[1,11,20],
       'range_end':[4,15,23],
       'score':[3,8,5]}
output = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'range_start', 'range_end', 'score'])
```

Comment: What does row overlap mean?

Comment: Hi Rajesh, I meant two rows with ranges (range_start to range_end) overlapping

Comment: @CodyGlickman, could you please provide more examples and elaborate the logic behind you selection? Because in your example you drop id4 but keep id1 where both don't have any overlapping ranges in the example. What is the meaning and usage of score? Also which percentage did you use for your example. Ideally you would provide 2 samples with different percentages.

Comment: Hi Andreas, I would like to set an overlap threshold (called x_percentage in the function). The amount of overlap (overlap percentage is a measure of the overlap length divided by the full range of the overlapping ranges).

Comment: are the `range_start` & `range_end` values always integers, if not, can they be converted to integers?

Comment: also, why is `id4` not in out `output`?

Comment: Hi Haleemur Ali, id4 should be in the range of id1 and should be removed, this was changed in the description. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a cartesian join between all the ranges, then find length and % of the overlap for each pair, and filter it based on the `x_overlap` threshold.

After that, for each range we can find the overlapping range with the highest score (which could be the range itself, with the overlap of 100%):

```
# set min overlap parameter
x_overlap = 0.5

# cartesian join all ranges
z = df.assign(k=1).merge(
    df.assign(k=1), on='k', suffixes=['_1', '_2'])

# find lengths of overlaps
z['len_overlap'] = (
    z[['range_end_1', 'range_end_2']].min(axis=1) -
    z[['range_start_1', 'range_start_2']].max(axis=1)).clip(0)

# we're only interested in cases where ranges overlap, so the total
# range is the range between min(start1, start2) and max(end1, end2)
z['len_total'] = (
    z[['range_end_1', 'range_end_2']].max(axis=1) -
    z[['range_start_1', 'range_start_2']].min(axis=1)).clip(0)

# find % overlap and filter out pairs above threshold
# these include 'pairs' where a range is paired to itself
z['pct_overlap'] = z['len_overlap'] / z['len_total']
z = z[z['pct_overlap'] > x_overlap]

# for each range find an overlapping range with the highest score
# (could be the range itself)
z = z.sort_values('score_2').groupby('id_1')['id_2'].last()

# filter the inputs
df_out = df[df['id'].isin(z)]

df_out
```

Output:

```
    id  range_start  range_end  score
0  id1            1          4      3
2  id3           11         15      8
4  id5           20         23      5
```

P.S. Please note that it is not very clear what should happen with `id4` in your example. Since you don't have it in your output, I assumed (hopefully correctly) that you're not interested in zero-length ranges in the output

P.P.S. There is a new syntax for cartesian join in `pandas` 1.2.0+ with `how=cross` parameter in the `merge` method. I've used in my answer a version with a dummy variable `k=1`, which is more verbose, but compatible with older versions

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you perl

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a very clear definition of *overlap*. If you have [2;7], [6;10] and [7;8], which one overlaps with which one ?

Avoid using `input` as a variable name, it shadows the function `input()` (to get input from the user)

If you want to select clear overlaps (only the start or the end differs), and you only have at most ONE overlap, here you go:

```
sorted_df = df.sort_values(by=["range_start"])
starts_earlier = sorted_df[sorted_df.range_end.shift(-1) == sorted_df.range_end]

sorted_df = df.sort_values(by=["range_end"])
ends_earlier = sorted_df[sorted_df.range_start.shift(-1) == sorted_df.range_start]
```

Then you can do a `df.drop(starts_earlier.index)` and `df.drop(ends_earlier.index)` to remove the shorter ones/

`df.shift()` : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html

This code won't work for multiple overlapping segments. If you are interested in that, let me know.

Comment: Hi Sylvain, thankfully my data doesn't have chained overlaps (insert sigh of relief here). My data does have multiple ranges overlapping in which I would take the highest score (hence my dumb recursive approach). Overlap is defined by the length of the overlap divided by the full range of the overlapping ranges exceeds a user defined threshold. I am interested in multi-overlapping segments.